# Ruby: how to generate a json output with braces (brackets, parentheses, curlies) in a new line

Tags: ruby, json, pretty-print, braces

for a reference file compare a need the possibility to generate json files, where braces always start in a new line.

For Instance, the json hash:

```
my_json = {"Key" => {"Key" => "Value"}}
```

leads after the call of

```
JSON.pretty_generate(my_json)
```

to

```
{
  "Key": {
    "Key": "Value"
  }
}
```

But unfortunately I need an output like this:

```
{
  "Key": 
  {
    "Key": "Value"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to this with ruby without destroying the pretty formatting?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious why you need that specific output, they're both valid JSON (as would `{"Key":{"Key":"Value"}}` of course).

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `pretty_generate` that says to read [the `generate` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-generate) for options? Have you tried those options? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried a combination of :space=> "\n" and :indent=>"\t", but this not solves the problem, it destroys even the formatting. I don't want to have a new line after each ":" ... just after the braces and still to keep the pretty formatting

Comment: i second _mu is too short_'s comment. not trying to minimize your question but there shouldn't be a difference between where { are placed because it's JSON and regardless of whether they're on new lines or not the file is valid JSON!

Comment: okay, but the test environment in which I work makes a simple text compare between the json-files generated by me and the reference files generated somewhere else ... so an additinal new line in a reference file will probably lead to a negative diff-result.

Comment: Not sure if this works, but how about replacing with `.gsub(/: \{/,":\n{")`? Also you can backreference the white space of identation and prepend it to the latter line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you desire this difference in output, why don't you force it? As per my comment:

UPDATED to cover both `{` and `[` bracket

```
my_json = {"Keys" => [{"Key" => "Value"},{"key1" => "val2"}], "newkey" => {"nk1" => "val3"}}

puts JSON::pretty_generate(my_json).gsub(
           /^(.*)(\"[^\"]+\"): ([\{\[])/, #first brackets: white space. Second: Key, Third: Bracket
           "\\1\\2:\n\\1\\3")             #\\1: white space (on both lines), \\2: Key, \\3: Brac[e|ket]

{
  "Keys":
  [
    {
      "Key": "Value"
    },
    {
      "key1": "val2"
    }
  ],
  "newkey":
  {
    "nk1": "val3"
  }
}
```

Comment: that is a good approach, thanks so far. But can you edit your comment to work also with "[" braces ... in my test they don't start in a new line.